# Invalid service catalog: identity

Tags: devstack

Has anyone seen this after Dev stack install? I cannot find any logs or googles searches helping. Thank you in advance!

I have looked in a ton of different logs. This is on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but this seams to be a problem with "yoga" so I tried to install xena and then it work

git clone https://opendev.org/openstack/devstack -b stable/xena

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please share if you find a solution with Yoga without switching to the Xena project!